# PHP not capturing data sent on jquery submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

;;I have a form which allows users to dynamically add a new form input row. Each time a user creates a new row. The inputs are added as an array:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentItem = 1;
  $('#addnew').click(function(){
   currentItem++;
   $('#items').val(currentItem);
var strToAdd = '<tr><td>Year</td><td>:</td><td><select name="year[]"  ><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option></select></td><td width="7%">Week</td><td width="3%">:</td><td width="17%"><select name="week[]" ><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option></select></td><td width="8%">&nbsp;</td><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>Actual</td><td>:</td><td width="17%"><input name="actual[]"  type="text" /></td><td width="7%">Max</td> <td width="3%">:</td></tr>';
   $('#data').append(strToAdd);

  });
});
```

Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/zxdg750s/)

The problem I'm having is when I submit the form. I'm not able to capture any of the data through my php:

```
$("#upload").validate({


        submitHandler: function (form) { 

             $.ajax({
                 url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/ajax_upload',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: $(form).serialize(),

                 success: function(data) {
                    if(data)
                    {

                       alert("success");
                    } else {

                       alert("error");

                    }


                 },
                error: function(data){

                   alert("error");
                 },
                 cache: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false
             });

             return false;


    }


    });
```

When executing this code:

`var_dump($_POST['year']);` or `echo count($_POST['year'])`

I receive the following error: `Message:  Undefined index: year`

In my firebug under the console view. POST I see the data is being posted

```
year%5B%5D=2012&week%5B%5D=1&actual%5B%5D=test&year%5B%5D=2011&week%5B%5D=2&actual%5B%5D=test+2&items
=3&sub=Submit+values
```

but it still doesn't seem to be capturing.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your missing a closing ' on your $_POST access...  Also your firebug is showing you the key is being sent as `year%5B%5D` which is `year[]`  http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: It is `$(form).serializeArray()`.

Comment: @Cunning if they want it to be a string it is serialize()

Comment: can you just put `var_dump($_POST);` and see the result

Comment: $_POST['year'] it should be. The ending single quote is missing.

Comment: i did add the missing ' single quote, but still the same...

Comment: @NewbeeDev when a do a var_dump. i get this `array (size=0)
  empty`

Comment: check your network and it's header check if your $_POST data is in here https://gyazo.com/fb79a328d917c5b0230f3405acb4ac52